# How to match crypted password in php while login?

Tags: php, crypt

I am using PHP `crypt()`. Here I saved my password using crypt().

In login, I want to match my password with the input password and logged in password, but in crypt its everytime creating random string with the same password.

below is my login code.

```html
$user_name=$_REQUEST['username'];
$salt = "";
echo  $password=crypt($_REQUEST['password'], $salt);

$query ="select username , password from users where username = '".$user_name."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<pre>";print_r($row);exit;
```

login out put

```html
$1$oIllNdlE$y23rdM6qp4sv/P/bgfUE7/     //user input

Array
(
    [username] => sradha
    [password] => $1$dI1IgbiD$NsfWU0fOHOzNEFbd7Vrx.0  //from data base 
)
```

here my password is 123, for same 123 it's generating two different results.

below is the code I am inserting to DB, while sign in:

```html
user_name=$_REQUEST['username'];
$salt = "";
$password=crypt($_REQUEST['password'], $salt);
mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO users (username , password) VALUES ('sradha' , '".$password."')");
```

any suggestion, how to match the password using crypt?

Answer (score 1):

Crypt function returns the different data every time.
You can use [hash_equal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) function to compare the encrypted strings.

Comment: after adding a valid salt , its not returning different data every time .